# Javascript Closures. Lexical vs function context.

Tags: javascript, closures

My question is why the following code prints 1 instead of 500; 
  When the callback is invoked and it doesnt find the variable count, doesnt it first looked at the context of func1 ?

```
function func1(cb){
  let count = 500
  cb()
}


let count = 1

function func2() {
  console.log(count);
}


func1(func2)
```

Comment: You are confusing the runtime notion of scope (dynamic) with the compile-time notion of scope (lexical). When you call `cb()` the engine looks through the lexical scopes the function was defined in, not the runtime call stack.

Answer (score 0):

Let is the scope variable. And in func1 it’s just function scope variable. You should use one global scope variable instead of creating new one.

Answer (score 0):

That's a matter of scopes, the first `count` hasn't the same scope of the second one, different is this:

```js
    let count = 1
    
    function func2() {
      console.log(count);
    }
    
    
    function func1(cb){
      count = 500
      cb()
    }

    func1(func2)
```

There you got what you spected,

And also, if you do:

```js
    let count = 1
    
    function func2() {
      console.log(count);
    }
    
    
    function func1(cb){
      let count = 500
      cb()
    }
    func1(func2)
```

You are creating a new variable count, with different scope of the first count, meaning, it will print 1

Answer (score 0):

**1.** func1(func2)

You are passing a function func2 as an argument to the func1

**2.** let count = 1

You have declared **global variable**

**3.** You have passed the func2 to func1 as argument but you have done nothing there. You have declared the variable inside the function but still **it is out of the scope of func2**

```
function func1(cb){
  let count = 500
  cb()
}
```

**4.** func2 only **know the global count variable** so it **will console 1** **instead of local variable of func1**

```
function func2() {
  console.log(count);
}
```